# AWS EC2 AMI launch with user-data, but script doesn't work

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Before I wrote the script, I tried each command in the same order and it worked. What is wrong when I put them in a script?

The only commands executed from the script is the yum update and git install, that’s it.

Here is the script I'm trying to launch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
# Update packages
sudo yum update -y 


npm --version

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then

    sudo -u ec2-user bash <<EOF

        sudo yum install git -y

        export HOME=/root

        git clone https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo.git && cd adminMongo

        curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash

        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

        nvm install node

        npm install

        cd.

EOF

fi

# changing localhost to everyone.
sudo sed -i 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/g' /home/ec2-user/adminmongo/app.js
```

Comment: What is the contents of `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`? You can also add `-x` on the first line to log the actual commands too.

Comment: Remember that by default user-data is only executed when the instance is created not on every reboot. If you modify user-data and reboot the instance it won't be executed.

Comment: => Downloading nvm from git to '/root/.nvm'
=> mkdir: cannot create directory '/root': Permission denied
ls: cannot access /root/.nvm: Permission denied
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/root/.nvm': Permission denied
Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!
bash: line 10: /root/.nvm/nvm.sh: Permission denied